# Will I loose my Windows Vista data by doing a full install of Lubuntu (LTS) 18.04.4?

Tags: dual-boot, lubuntu

I'm new to Linux/Ubuntu. I'm reading the Lubuntu manual as I go. So far I've successfully burned an image of Lubuntu 18.04.4 onto a DVD-R using InfraRecorder (recommended for Windows). I've been trying Lubuntu, using the boot menu and selecting the disc. I want to evaluate the OS prior to installation. Will I loose all of my Windows files (docs, photo's, music, MS accounting software, ESET antivirus protection, etc.) if I do a full Lubuntu install? Will my files and applications be integrated with Lubuntu? How can I try Lubuntu inside windows and access all of my files, and experience computing with Lubuntu with actual files?

Comment: Backup your data firstly (it's easy to make a mistake, have power go out during partition shrinks etc & data to be lost..), and carefully select your install.  I'd point you to the Lubuntu manual except it covers the modern Lubuntu (18.04 is legacy, the last of LXDE and has a year left of support yes, a re-install is required to move to modern Lubuntu). If you select any option which has 'format' you lose whatever data is on the area of the disk being formatted, so selection options carefully and then data won't get lost.

Comment: Official Lubuntu documentation can be found at https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/Installing_lubuntu.html  (Chapter 1.1 Retrieving the image - https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/1.1/retrieving_the_image.html
Chapter 1.2 Booting the Image - https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/1.2/booting_the_image.html
Chapter 1.3 Installation - https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/1.3/installation.html ) however it applies to modern Lubuntu which currently is 19.10

Comment: Thanks for the advise in backing up my computer. I was never able to completely backup my Vista Home Premium. The program would run, however, once it got to the end, it would say, backup not completed. I read somewhere recently that the Vista backup problem was consistent with my version. Can you recommend a more reliable option to backup my computer?

Comment: I've used 'vista' for less than ten hours in my life, so I couldn't help with it. I'll also provide only Ubuntu docs if possible, so https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DriveImaging https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PartitionImaging https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Clonezilla_Server_Edition though they probably aren't what you want.  Me I'd backup your system whilst in 'live' mode, so no files were in use, but as stated I have ~no experience with win.vista.

Comment: As for file integration, Lubuntu will only use it's own files on install, plus any file systems you add to your system (network shares, or local though ntfs/winfs file systems will be RO if they're in an unclean state; eg. you fast-boot or hibernate your windows system), and windows applications won't run in GNU/Linux systems (they use the wrong API/ABIs) so need something between then such as `wine` which works well with some apps/version, not well with others.

Comment: Most GNU/Linux users skip anti-virus, but if you share files with windows users it' matters if only to protect the windows users, is there a Linux version available? otherwise `clamav` is available, but malware protection in GNU/Linux differs as it exists primarily to detect malware for other users  (non-viral malware that impacts say chrome on windows will also impact chrome on Lubuntu, but anti-virus usually doesn't detect that anyway; users being smart is the best defence).

Comment: Thank you for your time and explanation... I'll start researching the links you provided. Should keep me busy for a while.

Comment: I've started to research the information you provided, it's been very helpful. I still plan to proceed slowly to ensure an easy backup and ultimately, a full Lubuntu install. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

No, you will not loose your data but it's recommended to back up your data in case something went wrong and to **follow** the the instruction [set up your computer in order to dual boot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) , you will be able to have 2 systems in your machine 
[dual boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XLCv.png) , Happy linux experience :)

Comment: Thank you for the information, it's looks informative and helpful. I will review in detail and begin the process when I can think clearly.